# In CVS how to commit all files as binary except a few whitelist

Tags: version-control, cvs, cvsnt

Can CVS cvswrappers be set up to treat all files as binary except for a few whitelisted extension?

Usually cvswrappers is used the other way around, ie. list all extensions which want to have keyword expansion -kb:

```
*.exe -k 'b'
```

But I need it the other way, so everything will be added/committed with -kb but everything else in the list is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but you should be able to put a binary wildcard at the end and your whitelist extensions above that with the default keyword expansion. e.g.

```
*.txt -k 'kkv'
* -k 'b'
```

You might even be able to omit explicitly mentioning the default expansion mode, given the fact that it is the default. e.g.

```
*.txt
* -k 'b'
```

Stepping back a bit, the only reason behind marking a file as binary is to stop keyword expansion. If you don't care about keyword expansion then you could just disable it by having the wildcard binary entry in `CVSROOT/cvswrappers` or alternatively adding the following to `CVSROOT/config`:

```
# Do not expand any RCS keywords
KeywordExpand=i
```

References:

- [Substitution modes](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.12.13/cvs_12.html#SEC103)
- [Configuring keyword expansion](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.12.13/cvs_12.html#SEC104)

Comment: Burhan, thanks for that. It works with a minor modification after modifying -k 'kkv' to -k 'kv'